# How to merge two lists into one in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 lists,

```
x = ['mandana', 'hamid', 'sina', 'sara', 'soheila', 'ali', 'sarvin']

y = [0, 16.3, 16, 13, 19, 2, 17, 8]
```

the number of values in 2 lists are always the same
how can I merge them together like this into another list?
to look something like this :

```
[('mandana',0), ('hamid', 16.3) , ...]
```

I have tried some of the solutions in search but non was successful.
sorry for stupid question.

update :
i already tried zip function, gets me error :
'float' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's zip function may be all that you need.
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

```
x = ['mandana', 'hamid', 'sina', 'sara', 'soheila', 'ali', 'sarvin']
y = [0, 16.3, 16, 13, 19, 2, 17, 8]
print(list(zip(x,y)))
```

This outputs: [('mandana', 0), ('hamid', 16.3), ('sina', 16), ('sara', 13), ('soheila', 19), ('ali', 2), ('sarvin', 17)]

Comment: Show your code please